# bash replacing multiple different string characters

Tags: string, bash, character

Anyway to simplify these two into one:

```
temp=${i//[/\\[}
temp=${temp//]/\\]}
```

input:

```
i[1]
i[2]
```

output:

```
i\[1\]
i\[2\]
```

Comment: I don't think so. The parameter in `${param/pattern/string}` has to be a parameter name, it can't be an expression.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed 's/[][]/\\&/g' foo.txt
```

- in each line look for `[` or `]`
- put `\` before each occurance